Least number of circles required to cover a continuous function on $[a,b]$
I asked this question on MSE here.

Given a continuous function  $f :[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, what is the least number of  closed circles with fixed radius $r$ required to cover the graph of $f$?
It is easy to prove (by using the extreme value theorem) that only finitely many circles  are required to cover the graph of $f$, but how can I find the least number of circles? I don't think a closed form exists , but is there a solution, like an indefinite integral? If there isn't, is there an algorithm that can solve this problem?

Assuming by circles you mean balls, this question is related to the box-counting dimension and/or Hausdorff measure of the graph as a subset of the plane.

More general questions of this nature are discussed at https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/202310/noti2799/noti2799.html?adat=November%202023&trk=2799&pdfissue=202310&pdffile=rnoti-p1584.pdf&cat=none&type=.html

@Teri But I don't think this would give the least number of circles.
